# Input an arbitrary number of files to matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following matplotlib python code that makes a plot from a file that contains just two columns with x,y values:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import string
import pylab
from pylab import *
import sys,os

narg=len(sys.argv)
print narg
if narg != 7:
    print "@Usage: python get_pic.py results_file output_filename xmin xmax ymin ymax"
    sys.exit()

res1 = sys.argv[1] 
res_file_1 = open(res1,"r")
fileoutput = sys.argv[2]
xmin =float( sys.argv[3])
xmax =float( sys.argv[4])
ymin =float( sys.argv[5])
ymax =float( sys.argv[6])


x1=[]
y1=[]

for line in res_file_1.readlines():
    ll=string.split(line)
    x1.append(float(ll[0]))
    y1.append(float(ll[1]))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
# ax.set_yscale('log')
# ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_xlabel('NSTEPS')
ax.set_ylabel("RMSD")
ax.set_xlim(xmin,xmax)
ax.set_ylim(ymin,ymax)
ax.plot(x1,y1,color='blue')


pylab.legend((
r'AVERAGE',), shadow = True, loc = 2,numpoints = 1)
ltext = pylab.gca().get_legend().get_texts()
pylab.setp(ltext[0], fontsize = 13)
plt.savefig(fileoutput,dpi=300)
plt.show()
```

The problem I am facing now is that I need to plot an arbitrary number of files (from 5 to 50). I started with the naïve approach, from this previous code, telling the script to open 5 different input files and so on, but it gets a mess and need to change the code depending on the number of input files, and furthermore, it becomes untractable for 50 files. So, how could I minimally modify my previous code so that it can read an arbitrary number of files?

P.S.: I would like all the plots in the same figure such as in this [example](http://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S0010465507004614-gr002.jpg).
P.S.2.: Also if consecutive plots can have either different colors randomly or following the rainbow scale.

Comment: How do you want the numerous plots to be displayed?

Comment: I have updated the question with an example, thanks

Comment: Is the problem related to iterating over sys.argv or something else ?

Comment: Do you mean I could try iteratively some check whether there are still data files present in the directory and if not then I have the number of files? I could also do that passing the exact number of files, since I know that number. The main problem is the rest of the code; how do I make exactly "n" plots in teh same figure.

Comment: To do a second plot you just call `ax.plot(x2, y2, color='red')` for example, where `x2, y2` comes from another data. So your actual problem is iterating over the files in a directory and reading them ? Did you try something like `glob.glob(*.data)`, supposing your files end with the .data extension ?

Comment: You can use `subplot(a, b, c)`, where `a, b, c` are dynamically adjusted to make sure you have exactly `n = a * b` plots in the same figure.